# Python How to get event in turtle window?

Tags: python-3.x, events, turtle-graphics

I am making a turtle interface that is managed with the keyboard.
I've made this at the moment:

```
from turtle import *
forward(0)#To activate the window.
def tur(event):
    direct = 'right'
    pen = 'down'
    if event == '<Space>':
        if pen == 'down':
            penup()
            print('Pen up!')
            pen = 'up'
        if pen == 'up':
            pendown()
            print('Pen down!')
            pen = 'down'
    elif event == '<Right>':
        right(90)
        forward(10)
    elif event == '<Left>':
        left(90)
        forward(10)
    elif event == '<Up>':
        forward(100)
    elif event == '<Down>':
        backward(10)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    canvasVaribleName.bind(['<Space>', '<Right>', '<Left>', '<Up>', '<Down>'], 
                           tur)
```

But how the canvas varible is called in turtle? Or maybe I should get events another way?
Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical way of doing what your code implies, using a turtle, is:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

def toggle_pen():
    if turtle.isdown():
        turtle.penup()
    else:
        turtle.pendown()

screen.onkey(toggle_pen, "space")

def right():
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(10)

screen.onkey(right, "Right")

def left():
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(10)

screen.onkey(left, "Left")

def forward():
    turtle.forward(100)

screen.onkey(forward, "Up")

def backward():
    turtle.backward(10)

screen.onkey(backward, "Down")

turtle = Turtle()

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

You might read one of the online Python turtle tutorials, particularly the section on how events are handled.